# How do I identify the source application when using universal deep links?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

When handling Universal links, I am meant to implement:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willContinueUserActivityWithType:(NSString *)userActivityType
```

When handling traditional URL schemes I used:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

How do I get the source application from the former method?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this from another source?

Comment: @sjwarner I don't think you can -- best solution right now is to embed query params into the URL.

Comment: Yep, that's the conclusion I'd come to as well. Cheers for the reply!